# Webserver 404 with Airflow Deployed on Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, minikube

I followed the instructions in the official repo on installing on kubernetes, however I get a 404 when I try to use the UI. Could anyone tell me what the issue might be?

Repo:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/scripts/ci/kubernetes

To clarify, the instructions I followed were:

- Point kubectl to the local minikube cluster (v1.10.0)
- Clone repo (commit 89c1f530da04088300312ad3cec9fa74c3703176)
- cd incubator-airflow/scripts/ci/kubernetes
- ./docker/build.sh
- ./kube/deploy.sh

[image: kubectl get pods airflow]
[image: airflow minikube 404]

Answer (score 2):

nevermind... I must have missed the memo that the default username/password is airflow/airflow even though I thought that authenticate was set to False.

Solution:

Go to localhost:8080/login and enter username/password airflow/airflow.

Comment: Those scripts have `rbac=True` - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1c76e8a9a580994e44edc7cc8d3b5bf17f4596ff/scripts/ci/kubernetes/kube/configmaps.yaml#L159 which only works with authentication, so the value of authenticate is ignored.